# Handsontable - Update CSS Property of Cell and Maintain Current Cell Renderer

Tags: javascript, css, handsontable

I have created a Handsontable and added conditional formatting to the table by assigning a specific cell renderer to each cell based off the value in the table column 'MIN_REMAINING_LIFE'. As per the instructions on the Handsontable website.

https://docs.handsontable.com/0.31.2/demo-conditional-formatting.html

And this works fine. My table rows change color depending on the value in the 'MIN_REMAINING_LIFE' column. However, when I go to overwrite another css property (making the row bold in this case) in any of these rows with a renderer already assigned. Nothing happens. The renderer will not update its value. I have provided my code which attempts to update the renderer on double click below.

```
var addDblClick = function (tableName, hot) {
  hot.view.wt.update('onCellDblClick', function (row, cell) {
    var selectedRow = hot.getSelected()[0];
    addHighlightRow(hot, selectedRow);
  });
}

var addHighlightRow = function (hot, selectedRow) {
      if (selectedRow != null) {
        var columnTotal = hot.countCols();
        for (var i=0;i<columnTotal;i++) {
          hot.getCellMeta(selectedRow, i).renderer = selectedRowCellRenderer
        }
        hot.render();
      }
}

var selectedRowCellRenderer = function (instance, td, row, col, prop, value, cellProperties) {
  Handsontable.renderers.TextRenderer.apply(this, arguments);
  td.style.color = 'black';
  td.style.fontWeight = '800';
}
```

I have also created a fiddle of this particular issue. See link below.

https://jsfiddle.net/JoshAdams/w8amwLvb/

You can replicate the issue by following the screenshots below.

[image: Conditional Formatting Bug]

So my question is. How can I update the "Bold" property (or any css property for that matter) of the row but still maintain the current conditional formatting renderer applied to the cell?